# How to get BNB ERC-20 address from Binance API?

Tags: erc-20, exchange-api

I was going trying to use the binance API for getting the token address for the BNB ERC-20 token.

But using just BNB as the asset name returns the Binance Chain address for the BNB token.

I have tried the following asset names,

BNBERC-20, BNBERC, EBNB, BNB-ERC20. You get the drift. Does anyone know what is the token/asset name so that I can retrieve the token address for BNB ERC-20 token for my account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing `network='ETH'` into the request payload worked for me.

I tried with the [python-binance library](https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html), so:

```
from binance.client import Client
client = Client(api_key, api_secret)
print(client.get_deposit_address(asset='BNB',network='ETH'))
```